# Confusing variable assignment in Functional-Light JavaScript by Kyle Simpson var[key] =

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, variable-assignment

So in the book Functional-Light JavaScript by Kyle Simpson he has a chapter on currying functions with the following code example:

```
function curryProps(fn, arity = 1) {
     return (function nextCurried(prevObjsArgs) {
          return function curried(nextArgObj = {}) {
               var [key] = Objects.keys( nextArgObj) ;
               var allArgsObj = Object.assign( {}, prevArgsObj, { [key] : nextArgObj[key] } );

          if (Object.keys( allArgsObj ).length >= arity) {
               return fn( allArgsObj );
          } else {
                return nextCurried( allArgsObj );
          }
     };
 })( {} );
```

}

I typed that on mobile so forgive any typos, but my question is about what key codes on line 4 of the function. Where he assigns: var[key] = ... I cannot seem to find any information on naming a variable with square brackets and so he completely loses me at that point. What can I say, I read code like a compiler and when I come across something I believe to be in violation of the rules I get tripped up. Can someone help me mentally compile this passage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is variable (array) [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
var arr = [1,2,3]; 
var [x, y] = arr; // assigns 1 to x and 2 to y.
```

In his case `Object.keys` returns an array of the keys in the array. He is extracting just the first element:

```
var o = {x:3, y:6, z:4};
var [p] = Object.keys(o); // just the first key
```

Answer (score 0):

He's using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it's pretty much the same thing as

```
var key = Object.keys( nextArgObj)[0];
```